# Java Web App Crashes on Heroku with webapp-runner

Tags: java

I have an existing Java web app project. It works locally with Tomcat. I converted it into a maven project and deployed it on Heroku using webapp-runner. The application is deployed successfully but it does not run; it crashes. I cannot figure out from the logs what the reason is.

My Procfile looks like this: web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war

**App structure**
[image]

**logs**
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
The specified path "target/*.war" does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It states clearly in the log: `The specified path target/*.war does not exist`. Run your build locally using `mvn clean package` and see if you actually have a war file in the target directory and what it's name is.

Then, open your `Procfile` and replace `target/*.war` with `target/whateverTheNameIs.war` and retry.

Comment: thank you, it's done but *.war didnt' appear: https://i.gyazo.com/0313b27e0bd59d102064e30dceb5afd5.png

Comment: What do you mean by `*.war` didn't appear?

Comment: Ah, I see. Don't look for it in `pom.xml`, the file I meant is called `Procfile`. It contains the heroku configuration.

Comment: after I built my app locally, i see only target/HotelSuiteBookingProject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar and target/dependencies/webapp-runner.jar. I thought the maven creates a .war of project.

Comment: But I don't see in the target directory this war file

Comment: As for the Procfile, I understand

Comment: In that case, open `pom.xml` and look for `<packaging>jar</packaging>` and change it to `<packaging>war</packaging>`. If you can't find it, just add it to your pom

Comment: great, thank you. also added a plugin to build a WAR and it was created

Comment: I have deployed and faced 404 mistake:HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report

Message /

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/8.5.30

Comment: I suppose my web directory with jsp pages isn't in WAR file or target directory. 
 If it is, how could I fix this? https://i.gyazo.com/df1a23fbf9365c937cdc78ec00729b83.png

Comment: 404s can have many reasons. Rename the war file to `something.zip` and open it in WinRAR to see the contents of the war file. If you find your jsps in there, the 404 has a different reason. However, this is kind of getting off topic, consider asking a new question for that issue.

Comment: thanks! I added a directory webapp in src/main and copied there WEB-INF with all jsp files and it works :)

Comment: Btw, would you mind accepting my answer as a solution if it worked for you? Thanks :)